# How to get wix velo breadcrumbs to show full path

Tags: breadcrumbs, velo

I have added the breadcrumbs component to my header but all I get when navigating in the site is Home>Current Page instead of Home>top level oage>current page

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to know what you want without knowing the structure of your site. But you can control what shows up in the breadcrumbs using the [`items`](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/breadcrumbs/items) property.